# Запись видео в json файл на python

Tags: python, json, видео

Можно ли, используя python, скачать видео файлы с YouTube с их категориями и хэштегами и записать это всё в json файл так, чтобы были пары: видео: категория и хэштеги? И если да, то подскажите как лучше это сделать.

Comment: В чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Можно ли сам видео файл записать в файл .json?

Comment: Да, можно. Любой файл представляет из себя последовательность байт, которую можно конвертировать в список байт, а затем этот список запихнуть в json. При декодировании этот список надо будет обратно проинтерпретировать как последовательность байт. Это неоптимальное решение, просто первое, что пришло на ум.